# .htaccess map non existing directory to a URL proxy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, proxy

I have 2 domains:

1. `sub.domain1.com/page`
2. `sub.domain2.com/page` <-- 'page' is a non-existing directory

How do I do it in `.htaccess` so that the URL is `sub.domain2.com/page`, but the user should see the page of `sub.domain1.com/page`?

Comment: Do sub.domain1.com and sub.domain2.com exist as different virtualhosts on the same server? If not, you cannot silently rewrite into a different domain - you must force the browser to redirect

Comment: If they are vhosts on the same server, what are their directory structures?

Comment: Hi @MichaelBerkowski, sub.domain1.com/page is a wordpress page on /var/www/wordpress/. sub.domain2.com/page is a cname pointed to the wordpress server.  When I tried to browse sub.domain2.com on browser, it will show the index.html in /var/www/ . When try to browse sub.domain2.com/page, it will show "The requested URL /page/ was not found on this server.". Thank you

Comment: Hi @MichaelBerkowski, its working now..

Comment: Here are steps I made. Followed some instructions here: http://abhirama.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/apache-mod_proxy-in-ubuntu/ but instead of apache2.conf file... I added the following entries at /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    ProxyPass /page/  sub.domain1.com/page
    ProxyPassReverse /page/  sub.domain1.com/page
</VirtualHost>
Thanks